# Azure Stream Analytics alternative to Sparks mapWithState

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Is there a way in Azure Stream Analytics to create some aggregation with a custom state like Sparks mapWithState does?

Here is my scenario:

I have data from IoT devices containing the following fields:

- DeviceId
- Position
- Value

The data may arrive out of order.

Whenever a new packet arrives for a given DeviceId, I want to output the last n positions and values for that device. Like

Input:
`{ "DeviceId": "A", "Position": 10, "Value": 100}`

Output:
`{ "DeviceId": "A", "Positions": [10], "Value": [100]}`

---

Next Input:
`{ "DeviceId": "A", "Position": 11, "Value": 101}`

Output:
`{ "DeviceId": "A", "Positions": [10, 11], "Value": [100, 101]}`

---

Next Input:
`{ "DeviceId": "A", "Position": 9, "Value": 99}`

Output:
`{ "DeviceId": "A", "Positions": [9, 10, 11], "Value": [9, 100, 101]}`

In Spark Structured Streaming I would implement this using `groupBy` and `mapWithState`. Is there a way to implement this in ASA?

Answer (score 1):

in ASA, you can use one of the following methods to do this:

- if you have an additional column that can be use for TIMESTAMP, you
  can use TIMESTAMP BY and ASA will reorder the events. Then you can
  use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/lag-azure-stream-analytics) to fetch latest events for this particular device.
- without any timestamp column, you can create [COLLECTTOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/collecttop-azure-stream-analytics) operator, and order the events according to your "Position" column
- alternatively, you can implement your own stateful logic using User Defined Aggregates (UDA) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-aggregates).

Let me know if you need help to implement one of these 3 methods. I'll be happy to provide further details.

Thanks,

JS

Comment: My data can arrive out of order and might be up to a day late. But when a message arrives, I want the updated state broadcasted as soon as possible. I didn't find a way to achieve that with the supported time window functions. Thanks for pointing me to UDA. I will give them a try.